# Position contents of collapsing Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navbar that partially collapses. In the alignment of elements on the navbar, the icon is in the wrong position. I would like the icon to be on the right, just in front of the collapse button, as shown in the below image.

[image: desired image].

I have tried lots of different combination but have been unable to position it correctly.

How do I move the icon to the other side of the navbar?

Below is my code and the undesired output with the icon on the left

[image: undesired output]
<sub>(source: [geekgirls.org](https://www.geekgirls.org/calyce/stackoverflow/bad.png))</sub>
.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          <a class="btn navbar-btn navbar-right btn-social-icon btn-xs btn-twitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{title}}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Please post the correct code. The HTML you posted is not for the first picture.

Comment: The first picture is the desired result. It is edited.
The second picture is the result of the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class `pull-right` to the button containing the icon.

```
<a class="btn navbar-btn navbar-right btn-social-icon btn-xs btn-twitter pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</a>
```